# @Order-ing of @Configuration for bean overriding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am in need to have beans defined in certain order for the sake of later bean overriding.

All is done through `java-config` and `@Configuration` annotations.

As it seems, `@Order` on nested static classes annotated with `@Configuration` is not working as expected. (moving nested class up/down within enclosing class changes the outcome, renaming methods too - so alphanumerical order matters)

I've reproduced the issue here:
https://github.com/mironbalcerzak/poc-spring-config-ordering

What are your thoughts? I don't want to do a bug report just yet.

Tested on:

- 5.2.24.RELEASE
- 5.3.28
- 6.0.10

Thanks

Comment: If configuration of dependency injection needs such a complex structure thats a big smell to me - try to find an alternative solution to your problem, maybe with Spring profiles. If you need such a delicate configuration it is likely to be misunderstood by other devs or might break easily in future versions of Spring.

Comment: @cyberbrian, thank you for your comment - it cannot nor will be changed. it's neither delicate nor misunderstood by other devs - it's doing exactly what it is supposed to do =) it has got very good reason to be the way it is. Any clues why it's behaving strange?